# what are the phase relationship between 4 and 8 ohm speakers

Tags: phase, ohms

What is the phase relationship between a 4ohm speaker and a 8ohm speaker used together? To be more specific I want to use a 8ohm and 4ohm speaker in the same cabinet but i do not know if they will have a canceling effect or a wrong polarity effect. making them sound out of phase with each other.

Comment: What do you mean by "used together"?  And, perhaps more importantly, what do you mean by "phase relationship"?  As asked, this question is essentially unanswerable and will likely be closed unless it is clarified.

Comment: That is entirely dependent on the physical positioning and frequency response of each driver. It's not definite and is impossible to answer on anything but a case by case basis.

Answer (score 2):

The phase relationship is not a function of the impedance of the speaker. The phase relationship refers to the movement of the speaker cone, according to the polarity of the applied signal, and is usually indicated on the terminals of the speaker.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fy_lFNnTnHA) can give you an idea about how to determine the phase of a speaker.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, impedance does not affect the phase of the audio coming from the speakers.

It is important, though, to understand impedance (the number of ohms in a speaker) and its implications in your audio setup.

Amps are typically designed to deliver power to speakers of a particular impedance (for example, 8ohms). If you use a speaker with half the impedance (I.E. a 4 ohm speaker instead of an 8 ohm), then you will effectively double the amount of power the speaker pulls from the amp (also increasing the volume). This will quickly overheat, if not destroy, your amp, if its not designed to handle lower impedances.

Connecting multiple speakers to the same output (if that is what you are doing) will change the impedance that the amp "sees" at that output. If the speakers are in parallel, then you reduce the effective impedance, asking the amp for more power. If they are in series (so positive terminal of one speaker wired to negative terminal of the other) then you increase the effective impedance.